# why use multiple Mutex in a file or struct?

Tags: c, mutex

If a mutex can lock a region of variable, why use multiple of them?

EX1 : (global variable)

```
static DEFINE_MUTEX(core_list_lock);
static LIST_HEAD(core_list);
static DEFINE_MUTEX(module_list_lock);
static LIST_HEAD(module_list);
```

instead of

```
static DEFINE_MUTEX(lock);
static LIST_HEAD(core_list);
static LIST_HEAD(module_list);
```

EX2 : (for structure)

```
struct core_data {
    struct list_head node;
    struct list_head module_list;
    char core_id[20];
    struct device *dev;
    struct list_head atten_list[CY_ATTEN_NUM_ATTEN];
    struct list_head param_list;
    struct mutex module_list_lock;
    struct mutex system_lock;
    struct mutex adap_lock;
    struct mutex hid_report_lock;
}
```

instead of

```
struct core_data {
    struct list_head node;
    struct list_head module_list;
    char core_id[20];
    struct device *dev;
    struct list_head atten_list[CY_ATTEN_NUM_ATTEN];
    struct list_head param_list;
    struct mutex lock;
}
```

Comment: With multiple mutexes one thread can work on (modify) one list while another thread works on the other - that can't happen with just one mutex. On the other hand, having multiple mutexes is an invitation to potential dead-lock situations if multiple threads wish to potentially work on both lists simultaneously.

Comment: Why have locks to individual rooms in a house when you can just have one lock on the front door?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError : Isn't core_list_lock or module_list_lock is acquired then both list are locked ? Why is there another thread that can work on list ?

Comment: We can't tell from what you've posted how the mutexes are acquired.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError It's acquired by mutex_lock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the comment of @klutt: `Why have locks to individual rooms in a house when you can just have one lock on the front door?`

I have small example of using two mutex for changing two independent variables: `int a` and `int b`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int a, b;

pthread_mutex_t m1, m2;
void * increase_a(void * data) {
    for(int i = 0; i <10; i++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m1);
        a++;
        printf("increase a = %d\n", a);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m1);
        sleep(1);
    }
}

void * decrease_a(void * data) {
    for(int i = 0; i <10; i++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m1);
        a--;
        printf("decrease a = %d\n", a);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m1);
        sleep(1);
    }
}

void * increase_b(void * data) {
    for(int i = 0; i <10; i++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m2);
        b++;
        printf("increase b = %d\n", b);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m2);
        sleep(1);
    }
}

void * decrease_b(void * data) {
    for(int i = 0; i <10; i++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m2);
        b--;
        printf("decrease b = %d\n", b);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m2);
        sleep(1);
    }
}


int main()
{
    pthread_t a1, a2, b1, b2;

    pthread_create(&a1, NULL, increase_a, NULL);
    pthread_create(&a2, NULL, decrease_a, NULL);
    pthread_create(&b1, NULL, increase_b, NULL); 
    pthread_create(&b2, NULL, decrease_b, NULL);

    pthread_join(a1, NULL); 
    pthread_join(a2, NULL);
    pthread_join(b1, NULL);
    pthread_join(b2, NULL);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&m1);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&m2);


    return 0;
}
```

Because in this code, `a` and `b` are independent (they do not shared memory, and do not impact each other), so you can change `a` and `b` at the same time.

If you use one mutex, you can not change `a` and `b` simultaneously (for example, when you change `a`, the other threads can not access b to change it because a is under mutex lock, and when you change `b` the other threads can not access `a`).

But when you use two mutex (one for `a` and another one for `b`), you can change `a` and `b` simultaneously. It means, the threads can access `a` and `b` at the same time.